# reversing char function but will not output

Tags: c++

I need a function to reverse a char array.

- It takes input as char array.
- It calls reverse function.
- It outputs the reversed array.

nvm this

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && count < 50)
```

Comment: show some efforts, code or logic !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code to reverse a character array.

```
#include <iostream>

void reverse(char * inputArray, int len) {
    std::cout << "Reverse is as follows: ";
    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        std::cout << inputArray[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::string myString;
    std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
    std::cin>>myString;

    int length = myString.length();
    char * charArray = new char[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        charArray[i] = myString[i];
    }

    reverse(charArray, length);

    return 0;
}
```

Here the function `reverse()` will print the character array passed as argument in reverse.

The output of the above code will be as follows:

```
Enter a string: Sample
Reverse is as follows: elpmaS
```

There are a number of ways to do this. Please share some solid code to have more apt response customized for your need.